# AngularJS, single controller or multiple controllers for ng-included views?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dashboard page. Say it is Student dashboard and it has lots of details about the student like his personal details, course details, project details and etc. Inside `student.html`  `personal-details.html`, `course-details.html`,`project-details.html` are included using `ng-include`. 
Student can view those details as well as they can edit it. For this functionality, I have written a single controller `StudentController` as follows,

```
(function(){
  "use strict";
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('StudentController',StudentController);
StudentController.$inject=['StudentService'];

function StudentController(StudentService){

     var vm = this;
     vm.studentData = null;
     vm.editPersonalDetails = editPersonalDetails();
     vm.editCourseDetails = editCourseDetails();

     activate();


     function activate(){
           StudentService.getStudent().then(queryStudentCompleted);
     }
     function queryStudentCompleted(res){
         vm.studentData = res.data;
     }

     function editPersonalDetails(){
         StudentService.editPersonalDetails(vm.studentData);
     }

     function editCourseDetails(){
        StudentService.editCourseDetails(vm.studentData);
     }

}
```

In my real application there are lots of panels to be shown and everything is editable.

1)Should I use different controller for different `ng-include`d pages or single controller is enough(think that more than 7 htmls are included and every panel is editable)? if yes how do the child controllers(say personalDetailsController, courseDetailsController which have edit methods in it) get access to the `vm.studentData` which is received in the `studentController`? In Page I can directly show it using `ControllerAs` syntax, but when I edit it I need to send the edited values to the child controller.. 
2)Currently `studentData` has every details that should be shown in the page. Should I keep that in that way or I need to split the data as well into smaller chunks?

Comment: To be more future proof I would implement this with Directives rather ng-include

Comment: @Simon, Thank you very much for your suggestion. Could you please provide me any example available online for this? As a newbie to angular, not able to visualize your thoughts..

Comment: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives